# Count price per quantity and show it on single total box via javascript in php

Tags: javascript, php

I'm getting an issue i am using while loop for fetching all offers from my database. All offers content name, price. I want to do is offer price must count with quantity(which will be updated by user) and show total in one box.

my code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#qty<?php echo $row1['sln_cart_id']; ?>, #price<?php echo $row1['sln_cart_id']; ?>').on('input',function() {
  var qty = parseInt($('#qty<?php echo $row1['sln_cart_id']; ?>').val());
  var price = parseFloat($('#price<?php echo $row1['sln_cart_id']; ?>').val());
  $('#total<?php echo $row1['sln_cart_id']; ?>').val((qty * price ? qty * price : 0).toFixed(2));
  });
</script>
<td class="qty">
  <input type='text' name='qty' id='qty<?php echo $row1['sln_cart_id'] ?>' value='1' />
</td>
<td class="unit-price hidden-xs">
  <span class="currency">
    Rs
  </span>
  <input type='text' name='price' id='price<?php echo $row1['sln_cart_id'] ?>' value='<?php echo $row1['sln_offer_price'] ?>' />
</td>
<td class="total-price">
  <span class="currency">
    Rs
  </span>
  <input type='text' name='total' id='total<?php echo $row1['sln_cart_id'] ?>' value='' />
</td>
```

Actually i want my result as. please see this link, So you will get proper direction
https://www.nearbuy.com/deal/ahmedabad/bodakdev/Black-Stain-Tattoo-Studio-14822/14822?list=Home%20Page

here is counter of amount per quantity

```js
$('#qty, #price').on('input', function() {
  var qty = parseInt($('#qty').val());
  var price = parseFloat($('#price').val());
  $('#total').val((qty * price ? qty * price : 0).toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class="qty">
  <input type='text' name='qty' id='qty' value='1' />
</td>
<td class="unit-price hidden-xs">
  <span class="currency">
                      Rs
                    </span>
  <input type='text' name='price' id='price' value='100' />
</td>
<td class="total-price">
  <span class="currency">
                      Rs
                    </span>
  <input type='text' name='total' id='total' value='' />
</td>
```

while loop----

```
<?php
            $sql1= "SELECT * FROM sln_customer_cart WHERE sln_customer_id='".$_SESSION['getincusid']."'";
            $result1= mysql_query($sql1);
            while($row1= mysql_fetch_array($result1))
            {
          ?>
            <tr>
              <td class="image hidden-xs">
                <?php $sql2="SELECT * FROM sln_vendor_deals WHERE sln_deal_id='".$row1['sln_deal_id']."'"; $result2= mysql_query($sql2); while($row2= mysql_fetch_array($result2)){ echo $row2['sln_deal_name'];} ?>
              </td>
              <td class="details">
                <div class="clearfix">
                  <div class="pull-left">
                    <a href="#" class="title">
                      <?php echo $row1['sln_offer_name']; ?>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="action pull-right">
                    <div class="clearfix">
                      <button class="btn-danger btn-raised ripple-effect">
                        <i class="ti-trash">
                        </i>
                      </button>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                $('.qtyin, .pricein').on('input', function() {
                      var row = $(this).closest("tr");
                      var qty = parseInt(row.find('.qtyin').val());
                      var price = parseFloat(row.find('.pricein').val());
                      row.find('.totalout').val((qty * price ? qty * price : 0).toFixed(2));
                    });
              </script>
              <td class="qty">
                <input type='text' name='qty' class="qtyin" id='qty' value='1' />
              </td>
              <td class="unit-price hidden-xs">
                <span class="currency">
                  Rs
                </span>
                <input type='text' name='price' class="pricein" id='price' value='<?php echo $row1['sln_offer_price'] ?>' />
              </td>
              <td class="total-price">
                <span class="currency">
                  Rs
                </span>
                <input type='text' name='total' class="totalout" id='total' value='' />
              </td>
            </tr>
          <?php
            }
          ?>
```

Comment: Can you share a fiddle ?

Comment: my code consist some php code so fiddle will not work

Comment: you can get my quation by clicking the link https://www.nearbuy.com/deal/ahmedabad/bodakdev/Black-Stain-Tattoo-Studio-14822/14822?list=Home%20Page

Comment: I am concerned about code..Not about the link you are sharing..You can copy parsed HTML and create a fiddle..

Comment: ok i will try to do that

Comment: i am fetching price in while loop, want to show total of all prices in one total

Comment: [___`ID(unique identifier)` must be unique___](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute)

Comment: The code you posted works. I fixed some syntax errors in the snippet.

Comment: @Barmar, I guess there are many `tr` elements having same `ID` and that is the culprit here!

Comment: @Rayon In his PHP he gives a unique ID to each element in the PHP loop.

Comment: @Barmar, I think you are right! ;)

Comment: i tried to give offer id to every id='qty1', id='qty2', id='price1', id='price2', like this when while loop excute. but whenever i put php code, it stop working

Comment: if you can help me out, how do i put php code plus while loop

Comment: @RahulRaghav Why do you think the inputs need IDs? My answer shows that you can just use the class, you don't need IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating an event binding for each ID in the PHP, give the elements classes and use DOM traversal functions to find the elements in the same row. Then you just need a single binding for the classes.

The jQuery code should not be in the `while` loop. It should be done just once, because it's binding to all elements with the same class.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.qtyin, .pricein').on('input', function() {
      var row = $(this).closest("tr");
      var qty = parseInt(row.find('.qtyin').val());
      var price = parseFloat(row.find('.pricein').val());
      row.find('.totalout').val((qty * price ? qty * price : 0).toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="qty">
      <input type='text' name='qty' class='qtyin' value='1' />
    </td>
    <td class="unit-price hidden-xs">
      <span class="currency">
                      Rs
                    </span>
      <input type='text' name='price' class='pricein' value='100' />
    </td>
    <td class="total-price">
      <span class="currency">
                      Rs
                    </span>
      <input type='text' name='total' class='totalout' value='' />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="qty">
      <input type='text' name='qty' class='qtyin' value='1' />
    </td>
    <td class="unit-price hidden-xs">
      <span class="currency">
                      Rs
                    </span>
      <input type='text' name='price' class='pricein' value='100' />
    </td>
    <td class="total-price">
      <span class="currency">
                      Rs
                    </span>
      <input type='text' name='total' class='totalout' value='' />
    </td>
  </tr>    </table>
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar i got it now, lemme put this code in my code then i will let you know if its work.

Comment: i have added an answer please see it and added an image as well, please check it out

Comment: Why did you post it as an answer if it's not working? Add it to the question.

Comment: i am sorry to put it in answer